# What does the PyTables warning "a closed node found in the registry" mean?

Tags: python, pandas, warnings, hdf5, pytables

When using pandas.to_hdf function to save data to a HDF5 file, I'm getting the following warning:

```
C:\{my path to conda environment}\lib\site-packages\tables\file.py:426: 
UserWarning: a closed node found in the registry: ``/{my object key}/meta/{my column name}/meta/_i_table``
  warnings.warn("a closed node found in the registry: "
```

I wasn't able to google what this warning could mean and looking into [the relevant PyTables docs](https://www.pytables.org/_modules/tables/file.html) didn't help.

Does anybody have an idea?

**Details:**

- Python 3.8.2, PyTables 3.6.1, pandas 1.0.3
- The saved data seem to be alright.
- I'm calling the pandas.to_hdf function as follows: `to_hdf(filename, key, mode = mode, complib='blosc', format = 'table', append = True)`, where mode is either 'w' or 'a' (the warning is raised in both cases).

Comment: i get the same think with python 3.9.8, Tables 3.6.1 and pandas 1.3.3

Answer (score 0):

For all its worth i managed to overcome the warning by installing tables 3.6.1 from:
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pytables](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pytables)
using the +gpl version for python 3.9.

Never the less i do not know the details of this choice and i cannot justify why it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same issue. For me, this happens (from time to time, I do not see the logic) for `category` columns in the DataFrame.

Solution:

- transform `category` columns to `object`
- run `to_hdf(...)`